# Can we write an custom check for monitoring a process with Data Dog

Tags: plugins, monitoring, nagios, infrastructure, datadog

I want to write an DataDog Check to monitor some process like Puma, delayed_job etc, I can see there are ready plugins available for these for nagios and Sensu but not for DataDog, But can I write my own check/plugin for this services in datadog ? or can I use existing Nagios/sensu plugins with DataDog ? If yes How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to proceed is to create a custom check. You can read up on this here: http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/agent_checks/. There isn't a way to take a pre-existing Nagios or Sensu plugin and have it work as is with Datadog, but looking at one of the delayed_job plugins on Github, looks like it should be pretty easy to convert to a Datadog check. If you have any issues, reach out to support either via email or #datadog on IRC.